# Código Java funciona em Mac, mas em PC não

Tags: java, eclipse

O seguinte código funciona no meu mac e no pc não. Preciso mesmo passar a trabalhar no pc, portanto agradeço qualquer ajuda que me consigam dar.
Estou a usar o Eclipse Java Oxygen em ambas as plataformas.

Código:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class coordinates {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {

       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\TelmoG\\Desktop\\06092017.txt")));
       PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\TelmoG\\Desktop\\outputFile.csv");

       String newLine ="";
       int index = 0;
       String line = "";

       while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
          // System.out.println(line);
           index++;

           if (index %2 == 0){
               newLine += ";" + line.substring(34);
               out.println(newLine);
           } else {
               newLine = line.substring(34);
           };  
       } 
       in.close();
       out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }      
 }
 }
```

Erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:
>
> at coordinates.coordinates.main(coordinates.java:25)
>
> Linha 25:
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {

Comment: Esse arquivo está dentro de alguma pasta? Ou está solto na raiz do diretório dos fontes?

Comment: O arquivo txt está no desktop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é devido a um erro de compilação - no eclipse deve dizer qual o erro - confira a View "Problems" ou a anotação a esquerda do painel com o código, provavelmente na primeira linha do código e eventualmente com a seguinte mensagem:

> The declared package "" does not match the expected package "coordinates"

Pelo código que postou, ou está faltando a declaração do package:

```
package coordinates;
```

ou o arquivo `coordinates.java` está no diretório errado: mova para o diretório 'pai' do `coordinates` (ou o projeto Eclipse está com o `Source folder` errado).

Comment: Problema resolvido. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Oi @Telmo Garcia. Se a resposta do Carlos resolveu seu problema, aceite-a (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Assim, quem estiver procurando por uma resolução para um caso semelhante vai saber que aqui tem uma resposta que potencialmente resolve. E também é uma forma de agradecer ao Carlos.

Comment: Ok mari. Já está aceite.